# Documentation for source code of wget

Tags: wget, documentation, source-code

I downloaded the source code of `wget` from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/ (file wget-1.14.tar.gz). Is there any place where I can read to understand the whole structure of the source code? I can't find any such file in what I downloaded.

Comment: The title asks for the source code of the documentation. For that look in the `doc/` directory. But the question asks for an explanation of the structure of the program's source code which is rather different.

Comment: @DanD. Sorry, I wasn't careful with the title. Edited :)

Comment: maybe this is where you can find whole documentation :http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not able to get documentation you can generate one using softwares like [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/)

It can help you in **three** ways:

It can generate an on-line documentation browser (in HTML) and/or an off-line reference manual (in ) from a set of documented source files. There is also support for generating output in RTF (MS-Word), PostScript, hyperlinked PDF, compressed HTML, and Unix man pages. The documentation is extracted directly from the sources, which makes it much easier to keep the documentation consistent with the source code.
You can configure doxygen to extract the code structure from undocumented source files. This is very useful to quickly find your way in large source distributions.

You can also visualize the relations between the various elements by means of include dependency graphs, inheritance diagrams, and collaboration diagrams, which are all generated automatically.

You can also use doxygen for creating normal documentation